# How to synchronize row header JTable scrolling with another table using keyboard arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

In a component class, I have 2 JTables, one is a fixed row header table and another is a data table that carries the values for the row header. I have a JScrollPane set for the data table such that it will scroll simultaneously for both tables.

In another class, I have a JPanel which I add the component class above to display.

In the panel, the scrolling of the tables is fine when I scroll using the mouse wheel or by clicking the scroll bars. However, if I select the row header and press the down or up arrow key from the keyboard, I notice that only the row header continues to scroll, but the data table does not move. Thus, the tables rows do not align properly anymore.

In another note, I noticed that if I select the data table row instead and scroll using the up/down arrow keys, both the tables are able to scroll properly in synchronization!

Would anyone know why is this so and how I may solve the scrolling problem if the row header table was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Fixed Column Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/)

The logic there uses a `ChangeListener` to synchronize the scrolling of the row header with the vertical scrollbar of the scrollpane.

The basic code is:

```
scrollPane.getRowHeader().addChangeListener( this );
```

and the listener:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{
    //  Sync the scroll pane scrollbar with the row header

    JViewport viewport = (JViewport) e.getSource();
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(viewport.getViewPosition().y);
}
```